# How to use Secure Enclave without TouchID and Passcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, security.framework

To generate key pair I am using Secure Enclave (kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave). When trying to access generated key pair, iOS system, asks for TouchID. Below is code snapshot how I am generating and accessing key pair.

*Is here a way to setup properties/attributes, that Secure Enclave functionality will be able to use without TouchID and Passcode?*

**Generate key pair:**

```
SecAccessControlRef sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked,
                                                kSecAccessControlUserPresence | kSecAccessControlPrivateKeyUsage, &error);

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenID: (__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType: (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @256,
        (__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: @{
            (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject,
            (__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent: @YES,
            (__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel: @“SecKey”,
        },
    };
SStatus status = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey);
```

**Access key pair:**

```
    NSDictionary *query = @{
        (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClass: (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel: @"SecKey",
        (__bridge id)kSecReturnRef: @YES
    };
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&privateKey);
```

Comment: how are you proposing that you extract the details if not with user authentication? surely that's just the keychain...

Comment: The whole point of Secure Enclave is that it holds data protected by Touch ID. If you don't want it protected by Touch ID, don't put it in the Secure Enclave.

Comment: Could some one of you post an answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is taken form Apple examples KeychainTouchID. By removing **kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny** it is possible to generate private key inside secure enclave and later use it without entering a passcode.

```
SecAccessControlRef sacObject;

// Should be the secret invalidated when passcode is removed? If not then use `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`.
sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
                                            /*kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny |*/ kSecAccessControlPrivateKeyUsage, &error);

// Create parameters dictionary for key generation.
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenID: (__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType: (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @256,
    (__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: @{
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent: @YES,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel: @"my-se-key",
    },
};
```